# Having Android 6.0 permission explanation in Unity project

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, permissions, android-6.0-marshmallow

The project is using Unity 5.3.4f1. and targeting Android 6.0. The app will have photos/videos/files Storage permission after the splash screen. The game will not run if the user deny the permission(Stop at splash screen). So we want to add explanation under this permission request. Any Help?

Comment: What do you mean by "add explanation under this permission request"?

Comment: On game start, app will be asked for Storage permission. But it has no explanation why the app need the permission. (Our game will read and write data by using Storage. Even thought we didn't put in the code, but Unity add for us and request this permission on app launch). If the user deny the permission, the game will stop at splash screen. If user deny twice and choose to "Never ask again", they will not able to play the game. But we want to tell them why we need the permission and send them to Setting the allow the permission.